# Trying to load layers to a control c#

Tags: c#, layer, rectangles

im trying to load some rectangles as "layers" of the form, i loaded an image as also a layer of the form, but the problem with those rectangles is that they "overlay" the image, erasing portions of it, i want them to be seen as boxes of the image to display info, and i also want to be able to overlay a rectangle onto another rectangle without erasing eachother.

here is the class of the rectangle

```
namespace Imagen_capas
{
   class rectangulotransp : UserControl
   {
      public Pen pen11;
      private Rectangle Myrectangle;



     public rectangulotransp(int x,int y,int alto, int ancho, Rectangle tamacontrol)
      {
          Size = tamacontrol.Size;
          Location = tamacontrol.Location;
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
          BackColor = Color.Transparent;
          Myrectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, alto, ancho);
          pen11 = nuevopen();


      }  


      private Pen nuevopen()
      {
          Pen mypen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
          return mypen1;
      }

      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
      {
          Graphics g = e.Graphics;
          g.DrawRectangle(pen11,Myrectangle);

          base.OnPaint(e);
      }
  }
```

}

And the code of the form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Imagen_capas
{   
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    rectangulotransp rect;
    rectangulotransp rect2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rect = new rectangulotransp(50, 14, 500, 100,new     Rectangle(0,0,Width+400,Height));
           // this.Controls.Add(rect);
             rect2 = new rectangulotransp(0, 50, 20, 100,new     Rectangle(20,50,Width,Height));
            this.Controls.Add(rect2);
            this.Controls.Add(rect);

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK UserControls do not support transparency. You could change your rectangle class to a non-control class and draw them with tranparency in the pain event.

Comment: WinForms doesn't do layering like that.  A transparent background just calls the parent's background to paint it, not the controls that are underneath it.  The solution is to not use a control at all, just create a class that holds the rectangle information and paint those objects in the container's paint event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you set Transparent background, the rectangle is using the Form Backcolor and it seems to you that is erasing the other rectangle.
Maybe you could try painting your transparent rectangle as 4 lines instead of a rectangle.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

my friends, i solved it in this way.

I created a class for the rectangle, and then another class for a control, in which i painted all the rectangles just like you told me, then the image, and then i added it as a layer of the form using the controls.add, in that way  i was also able to put an image under it without being erased by the rectangles.

thanks!!